# jQuery login error

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I am desperately trying to create a responsiv mobile part of my site, with so far positive result.
But when trying to create a login, I fall short.

Upon clicking the Log in button simply nothing happends...

View:

```
@model HiltiHaninge.Models.LoginModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Logga in";
}

@section Header{
@Html.ActionLink("Avbryt", "IndexMobile", "Home", null, new { data_icon = "arrow-l", data_rel = "back" })
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
}

<section id="loginForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { data_ajax = "false", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Detaljer</li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </li>
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="submit" value="Logga in" />
        </li>
    </ul>
}
</section>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So I can't figure out what the error is.

Comment: Is there a JS error when trying to submit the form? Or could validation be silently failing?

Comment: I have no idea. I dont get an exception or anything. Nothing happends. Check it out at [link](hiltihaninge.azurewebsites.net)
It worked fine yesterday but today it wont...haha

Comment: The login form submits nicely in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for input, at least somewhere down the line the code works. I tried it on a iPhone with Safari and Samsung with its original browser and nothing happened. Should I try and change the code somehow?

Comment: Can you debug in the phone somehow? Otherwise, tracking down the error could be difficult.

Comment: Tried configure it so I can use a browser to debug it. But nothing shows up thats gives me a hint regarding the issue....tricky one